# How to get average from picklist value field in Salesforce?

Tags: formula, formula-field, picklist, report-formula

I was wondering if anyone has come across this scenario?

I have one picklist field called Knowledge_Level and it has a rating range 0,1,2,3,4.  This picklist field is in a related object called Knowledge Base.

Each user is assigned a Knowledge_Level per area of expertise (PC skills, software skills, etc..), and each user has up to 1100 records for different skills.  There are 40 users, so 40 x 1100 = 44,000 total records.  I can view all users' levels associated by clicking a specific Knowledge_Level and seeing the various numerical value for each user.

I am wanting to create a formula field to average up the total for each area if expertise.

For example, PC Skills (AVG is 2 for all 40 users)
Software Skills (AVG is 3 for all 40 users)
Etc...

Is this possible considering that AVG function in a formula field referencing a picklist value isn't allowed in Salesforce?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can create formula field as follows,

```
VALUE(TEXT(Knowledge_Level__c))
```

Which convert the Piclist field values into `Number` value and then you can use this value in `report` to calculate `Average` value.

Thanks.